# window.location.href="location of file" is unable to download file from Mozilla.37 and IE-11 but it is working for chrome ,what to do

Tags: javascript

window location href ="location of file" is unable to download file from Mozilla.37 and IE-11 but it is working for chrome. Help is appreciated.

Comment: depends on the type of the file, for example some browsers display json, some trigger a download. extensions can also come into play.

Comment: Any answer to this? same problem here